# Population Growth asking to find $p(t)$ at time $t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Initial size of a population is $200$ and increases according to 
$\frac{dP}{dt}=kP^2$ with $k = 0.001$.

$(a)$ Find population size $P(t)$ at time $t$ [This part is confusing me on what's it is asking]
My attempt to get it set

$$dP/P^2 = kdt$$ 
$$-1/P = kt+C$$
$$-1/(kt+C) = P$$

Not sure how to get $P(t)$ on this.

$(b)$ find $\lim P(t)$ as $t\to 5$ (this been a while since doing limits just a reminder would be nice).

Answer (score 0):

The initial size is 200. That means $P(0)=200$. You also have $P(t)=-\frac1{kt+C}$. From these you can solve for $C$ and find $P(t)$ for any $t$.

Comment: So in other words when it's phrased this way it's asking for the general solution?

Comment: Yes. It is asking for a formula for $P(t)$. When you get the result, you'll see that it is only valid for $0\le t < 5$.

Comment: So then take P(t) = -1 / kt+C 

200 = -1/0+C 
C = -1/200 
C = -.005

P(t) = -1/kt-.005

Comment: Yeah, that's it. You should try adding some parentheses to your math to clarify the expressions: $P(t)=-1/(kt-.005)$.